# i have try to make regex for date so please suggest right way

Tags: c#, regex

i have try to make Regex that match this  format like "12-apr" or "23 jun" or continue take all month like Jan,feb,Mar,....Dec.

**In this Regex first two digit are always number and last 3 digit are taken only from 12 month like jan...to Dec.and also first two digit are not exceed than 31.**

And also sometime between that regex format contain "12-Apr" "12/Apr" "12/Apr" so we need Regex That pass all the above condition.

the string are like this "hello 12/may 789"  so from this i want only 12/may is for that i make the below regex.

also sometime possible that "hello 12/xyz 789" so this time the regex are do not match any thing because that xyz donot match with any month format from jan to Dec.

so that also need to pass this condition also.

**i try \b((0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])[ .-\]?[a-zA-Z]{3})\b regex for this Problem but that pass all the condition in when string are "hello 12/may 789". that also return 12/may.**

**but not satisfy my regex when string are "hello 12/xyz 789" my string also match 12/xyz and return that value.**

so it is possible to solve my problem using regex  or not ??

Comment: you may try `DateTime.TryParseExact` as mentioned in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `[A-Za-z]{3}` with `jan|feb|mar|....|dec`

```
@"(?i)\b((0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])[ \\.-/]?(jan|feb|mar|apr|may|ju[ln]|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec))\b"
```

But note that I could be able to modify to get upto 28 days for february but regex won't count for leap years. So don't parse dates with regex.

Comment: http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3fi)%5cb((0%3f%5b1-9%5d%7c%5b12%5d%5cd%7c3%5b01%5d)%5b+%5c%5c.-%2f%5d%3f(jan%7cfeb%7cmar%7capr%7cmay%7cju%5bln%5d%7caug%7csep%7coct%7cnov%7cdec))%5cb&i=12%2fmay%0d%0a12%2fabc

Answer (score 0):

Trt this one

```
/\b(?:0[\d]|1[\d]|2[\d]|30|31)+(?: |-|\/)(?:jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)/gim
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `DateTime.TryParseExact` to parse date for "dd/MMM" and "dd-MMM" formats by splitting your input strings.

It wont allow date greater than 31 and 29 for feb and corresponding for other months.

If you provide with year you could consider leap year also otherwise current year will be taken into account.

And for month part it will take abbreviation of months by using "MMM" and if you want to consider whole letters of month you could use "MMMM" (with pattern3 and `else if` condtion).

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace MyCOnsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string pattern1 = "dd/MMM";
            string pattern2 = "dd-MMM";
            DateTime parsedDate;
            string input = "hello 12/May 789";//your string
            string[] results = input.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.None);

            foreach (var result in results)
            {
                //pattern1
                if (DateTime.TryParseExact(result, pattern1, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                          DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate))
                    Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1:d} by pattern1.",
                                      result, parsedDate);
                //pattern2
                else if (DateTime.TryParseExact(result, pattern2, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                      DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate))
                    Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1:d} by pattern2.",
                                      result, parsedDate);
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert '{0}' to a date and time.",
                                      result);
            }

            //splitted values
            foreach (string s in results)
                Console.WriteLine(s);

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

More about:
[Custom date and Time string formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Note:I didn't use regex .But this is another easy option to solve your issue.**